# Can an American apply for an Israeli A2 visa from a third country?

Tags: visas, usa, covid-19, israel, residency

I am an American who has been hired as a researcher at an Israeli university. I have scheduled an appointment at the nearest consulate to receive an A2 visa, though the appointment was greatly delayed, largely due to COVID. I am interested in looking for other places where I might schedule an earlier appointment, including in Europe, where I currently am to see family.

I know that travelers to the USA can apply for an American visa from a "third" country (not their countries of residence), though this process is more delicate than the normal route. Is anything like this possible for Israel? I have not found any information online.

Comment: Where do you currently live?
(residency can matter for these questions as much as citizenship)

Comment: I live in the US and have been abroad for only a few weeks in a tourist capacity.

Comment: Have you contacted an Israeli embassy or consulate and asked?

Comment: I've downloaded the A2 application and I don't see anything that says you need to be inside your counter of residence or your country of origin when you apply. So I'd assume you can apply from anywhere.

Comment: @David Yes, though I haven't received a response yet. Naturally, I'll follow whatever their suggestions once I  receive them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the not-so-clear and ambiguous information from the Israeli immigrations website it is hard to obtain a definite answer.

On a personal note I have to say that if you are hired by Israelis you should ask them to deal with as much as possible of the process for you, even if it's just getting valid information, as the Israeli Immigrations Office is highly inefficient (from personal experience) and correct information is hard to come by.

Anyway, [the official page on A2 from the Israeli Immigrations Office website](https://www.gov.il/he/service/student_visa_application_type) states:

> #### מי יכול להגיש בקשה
>
> - נוכחות אישית חובה של הסטודנטים בנציגות ישראל במדינתם.
> - השירות ניתן לסטודנטים ולתלמידי ישיבות שאינם תושבי ישראל.
> - [stuff relevant for minors under 18]

***My*** translation:

> #### Who can submit a request
>
> - Physical presence is mandatory by the students in the Israeli consulate **of their country**.
> - The service is given to students which are not Israeli citizens.

Further down the page it also states (original redacted - my translation):

> #### How to submit a request
>
> After filling the [students' entry visa form](https://www.gov.il/BlobFolder/service/student_visa_application_type/he/MatanAshratKnisa_4.pdf) you need to
> personally arrive, with the *proper documentation*<sup>1</sup>, to the Immigrations
> office closest to your home or to an Israeli consulate **closest to your
> residence**.

I tried to keep the translation (specifically the bold parts) as closest to original as possible. It can be seen that it is not very clear whether *your country* and *closest to your residence* means your country of origin, or your current one. From the tone of the text, anyway, it feels like the emphasis is more on physical, personal appearance in a consulate, and less on which consulate it actually is.

---

<sup>[1] According to the same page, *proper documentation* means:</sup>

- An approval from the educational institute.
- An approval for paying tuition
- Proofs for [means of subsistence](https://translate.google.co.il/?hl=en&tab=rT&sl=auto&tl=en&text=%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%A2%D7%99%20%D7%9E%D7%97%D7%99%D7%94&op=translate) (vague term, Google translated).
- Valid foreign passport (valid through the extent of the visa).
- Up-to-date passport pictures (to be attached to the request).
- Original birth certificate.

Comment: Is there anything to indicate whether "of their country" denotes the country of residence or the country of citizenship, or whether it might allow someone who resides outside of the country of citizenship to choose either?

Comment: As I mentioned in the preface, the information is quite ambiguous and from experience it is hard to obtain reliable, hard-cut information from immigrations. I tried to make my translation stick as much as possible to the vagueness of the original. In the first paragraph I quoted, it literally says *"in their country"*, which could either mean country of origin, or country you are in... Similarly, the second paragraph basically says *"closest to where you live"*. Again, it doesn't say specifically country of origin and raises the question what if you live somewhere else...